# Channel Form change return & return_url with javascript

Tags: safecracker, channel-form, javascript, 2.7.0

I'm upgrading a site from 2.5.5 to 2.7.3 and I am running into an issue migrating one of my safecracker forms.  The values for return & return_url were being set using javascript in the safecracker form. The form would submit to 1 of 2 return templates based on information entered in the form.

When I upgraded the form, I seem to have lost the ability to change the return & return_url params & the form will only submit to the default return template when it is supposed to be returning to the alternate.

My Console is clean when submitting/viewing the page, so I think the issue has something to do with the new channel form open tags. Has anyone else encountered an issue like this upgrading a safecracker form?